# Facebook Sharer Returning 500 Internal Server Error on Desktop

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am attempting to use the share button on http://www.desiringgod.org/ on a Mac. It works for me on mobile, and on a desktop, the sharer dialog comes up properly. However, when clicking the Share Link button, dialog shows a short Facebook status bar and then does not respond. After inspecting in the browser's dev tool console, I see an 500 error.

Here's what I see in Firebug.
"POST https://www.facebook.com/ajax/sharer/submit_page/ 500 Internal Server Error"
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - //www.facebook.com/ajax/sharer/submit_page/"

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Any ideas on how to resolve?

It seems like a FB issue, but I can't find much else about this online or on FB forums.

Thanks!

Comment: I agree, this looks like a FaceBook issue, but it has been a problem for over a month now. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error and realized I was using a wrong app id. I'm not an admin of that faulty app id, so I don't know whether it was some settings in it (perhaps sandboxed) or something else. But changing it will definitely solve the issue for you

Comment: Thanks Michal! We found that if we removed the app ID, sharing started to work again. However, a random app ID was still put in the URL. Looks like I need to track down the app ID owner.

Comment: As an update, we removed the app ID and it worked for about a week and then started breaking again. Finally, I went ahead and applied for an app ID and used that ID. No problems since.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug on Facebook's behalf - as their Like button plugin doesn't require an appId and their Share Button code-generator doesn't include any references to it being required.

That said I've found a workaround that doesn't require signup/AppID-registration.

What I did was simply to copy any existing AppID and stuff it at the end of the `sdk.js` URL, Like so:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0&appId=XXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

(The one I used in place of the "XXX" above, was an App ID from one of Facebook's own sites.)

There seems to be no validation being performed, which again leads me to believe this is a temporary blunder made by Facebook.

Comment: Thanks Mar! It does seem like a FB bug, especially since it works on their mobile sharer page but not the desktop one. In the meantime, the most reliable workaround we found was to just get an app ID.

Comment: But the good news is that the AppID isn't validated against the domain, so you can reuse an AppID across multiple websites.